# facing problem in changing status bar color in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-12

I have two activities in my app, one is the `home.kt` and another is the `about.kt`, for both screens I have different background color, in the `home.kt` file I set the status bar color to background color.

```
rememberSystemUiController().setStatusBarColor(
    MaterialTheme.colors.background, darkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
)
```

When I move to `about.kt` I again tried to match its color to background but the status bar keeps its original color which was set in `home.kt`

```
rememberSystemUiController().setStatusBarColor(
    MaterialTheme.colors.surface, darkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight
)
//This piece is having no effect
```

Comment: Are you sure `surface` and `background` represent two different colors codes in your app?

Comment: @ArpitShukla Yes, sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each activity, instead of using:

`rememberSystemUiController().setStatusBarColor`,

set the statusbar color like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposePlaygroundTheme {
                window?.setStatusBarColor(Color.Red.toArgb())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit more, I am not getting a window property with class Activity

Comment: I updated my code sample.

Comment: It worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For that, too google has created a library called accompanist.
You can find it here: https://github.com/google/accompanist

like in this module have [multiple module](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/) for jetpack compose, system controller so you can change by using it

for more understanding see the document :-- https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/